# Convert an audio track with MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I was thinking of using MediaCodec to convert an arbitrary audio track to a fixed format (codec, sample rate, bitrate, etc.).

Reading the official docs, an obvious solution would be to use two loops. One for the decoder and one for the encoder and save the raw output data obtained from the decoder to a temporary file.

```
    for (;;) {
         ...
         ByteBuffer inputBuffer = decoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
         extractor.readSampleData(inputBuffer, 0);
         ...
         ByteBuffer outputBuffer = decoder.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex);
         ...
         // save contents of output buffer somewhere
    }

    for (;;) {
         ...
         ByteBuffer inputBuffer = encoder.getInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
         // read saved data into input buffer
         ...
         ByteBuffer outputBuffer = encoder.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex);
         ...
         mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(destAudioTrack, outputBuffer,...);
    }
```

Is there a way to efficiently chain the decoder -> encoder cycles, so only one loop and no temporary storage is needed?

[Edit]
Based on fadden's help and the code from DecodeEditEncodeTest.java I  attempted to copy buffers on the fly (currently truncating the contents of the input buffer if the output buffer is smaller). While this works fine on a Nexus 7, it doesn't work on a OPO with the same input file. Except for the first iteration, encoderInputBuf.remaining() is always 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (!decoderDone) {
  int decoderStatus = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
  ...
  if (decoderStatus >= 0) {
    if (bufferInfo.size != 0) {
    int inputBufIndex = encoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
    if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer decoderOutputBuf = decoderOutputBuffers[decoderStatus];
        ByteBuffer encoderInputBuf = encoderInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];

        int maxTransfer = Math.min(encoderInputBuf.remaining(), decoderOutputBuf.remaining());
        if (maxTransfer > 0) {
            ByteBuffer tmpByteBuf = decoderOutputBuf.duplicate();
            tmpByteBuf.limit (tmpByteBuf.position() + maxTransfer);
            encoderInputBuf.put(tmpByteBuf);
            }
        encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, maxTransfer, bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs, flags);
        ...
    }
    ...
    }
    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderStatus, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can see an example for video: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest `editVideoData()` uses nested loops.  The code would need to be tweaked for audio, but the idea is the same.  Feed the decoder; then while decoded buffers are available, feed the encoder.

Comment: The example is very useful, thanks! However it uses a Surface to render the video data. In case of audio, would it be enough to just copy over the contents of the output buffers of the decoder to the input buffers of the encoder?

Comment: My understanding is that copying from the decoder output to the encoder input would work, but I haven't really worked with audio.

Comment: I got it to work. At least on a Nexus 7 but not on other devices. Do you have any idea why? See edit for code.

Comment: Older versions of Android mis-handle ByteBuffers (see e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q11).  Make sure you `clear()` the output buffers and use the count from BufferInfo rather then what the ByteBuffer reports.  I think they may have fixed it for 5.0, which might be why it works on an N7.